# Who is the child who gives a scorpion to Daenerys?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is there any connection between the girl who gives a scorpion to Daenerys and Pyat Pree? Did Pyat Pree order the girl to do it? Because I thought Pyat Pree was already dead when the dragons burned him.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a Manticore, not a scorpion.

Comment: Yes, the assassin used a [manticore](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Manticore), which could be mistaken for a scorpion due to the tail.

Comment: @Justin: Of course, even more so since manticores are legendary creatures which may or may not exist in an imaginary kingdom, whereas scorpions exists here on earth. I just tried to be a bit more accurate is all. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, [the young girl](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Warlock) is a warlock, as she has [blue-stained lips](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shade_of_the_evening) and uses magic to escape. Presumably she was sent by other warlocks of the House of the Undying to assassinate Dany for killing Pyat Pree:

[image]

---

In the books the assassination attempt plays out slightly different. The warlocks want revenge on Dany for

> burning down their House of the Undying. So they hire one of the [Sorrowful Men](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sorrowful_Men) to assassinate her.

Dany recalls in [Chapter 8 of ASOS](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Storm_of_Swords-Chapter_8):

> Back in Qarth, the warlock Pyat Pree had sent a Sorrowful Man after her to avenge the Undying she'd burned in their House of Dust. Warlocks never forgot a wrong, it was said, and the Sorrowful Men never failed to kill.

Comment: If my memory serves me right when Ser Barristan thwarts the assassination attempt, the child exposes blueish mouth, which is probably how they knew it was the warlocks.

Comment: @LordSnow - Good catch, I don't remember the scene that well. This would be a great opportunity for someone to dig up a picture :)

Comment: Done and [done](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130402165149/gameofthrones/images/f/f2/Unidentified_warlock_S3_Ep1.png).

Comment: In the books it **was** a Sorrowful Man because Dany hears him say "I am so sorry" but doesn't quite catch it.

Comment: In the books, Pyat Pree does not die, and he and his allies are hunting Dany, seeking revenge. One can find that they are captured by Euron Greyjoy, if reading between the lines.

Comment: @Mooz So [the Tenth Doctor is a Sorrowful Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHVW-S9JkKA)?

Answer (score 5):

The child is an [Unidentified Warlock](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Warlock), most likely a surviving member of the [Warlocks of Qarth](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warlocks_of_Qarth). Note that her lips only go the blue shade once her assassination attempt has failed and she escapes.

[image: Warlock offers Dany the ball] [image: The warlock reveals herself]

Compare the colour of her lips to those of Pyat Pree and you can see they are pretty much the same.

[image: Pyat Pree]

As for if there's any connection, well the warlock is probably from the same group as Pyat Pree. Though he is already dead, having dies in Season 2 Episode 10, "Valar Morghulis". They probably wanted to get revenge on Dany. After Barristan Selmy saves Dany from the Manticore she comes to the same conclusion.

> Daenerys: **The Warlocks**
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 3 Episode 1, Valar Dohaeris</sub>

You can watch the scene here.

On a side note it is a [manticore](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Manticores) that the warlock uses in the attempt not a scorpion. The venom of this creature is what Oberyn Martell uses on his weapon in his fight against the Mountain so you can see it is highly dangerous.